# Perl package Tie::CSV_File

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to write some perl code for extracting information from a CSV file. Before I started to write the code from scratch, I've googled and checked `CPAN` to see what sort of perl modules there might exist to help and come across the package `Tie::CSV_File`.

My question/problem is this: I can't seem to install it from CPAN because the tests for that module have tons of errors. I can't find anything that explains how to get around this for this module. I even tried downloading the module directly and building it, but those errors are still there. I've used perl 5.10, 5.12 and 5.14 but the errors are still there and apparently still the same.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Does anyone have a good alternative to `Tie::CSV_File`? The reason I wanted to use it is because it will allow you to open the CSV file and treat it like an array, accessing each of the cells directly by addressing them with two-dimensional array syntax.

Thanks in advance for any insight you've got.

**Edit #1**
When I try to install Tie::CSV_File I'm getting the following error messages:

```
    Files=12, Tests=10,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.02 sys +  0.79 cusr  0.12 csys =  0.98 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 10/12 test programs. 4/10 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  BIGJ/Tie-CSV_File-0.21.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports BIGJ/Tie-CSV_File-0.21.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 BIGJ/Tie-CSV_File-0.21.tar.gz                : make_test NO
```

Comment: We need a lot more information here.  What kind of errors are you getting?  What platform are you on?  Some alternatives that may work are Tie::Handle::CSV or Text::CSV_XS.

Comment: If you have perl installed and cpan installed just do this: 'cpan install Tie::CSV_File' you will likely see the errors that I am talking about.

Comment: @Zeke Hansell, after trying to patch `Tie::CSV_File` I have decided to mock up my own, see my answer below.

Comment: @Zeke Hansell, try my new module `Tie::Array::CSV` to see if it helps you. (it may take a little bit to hit CPAN but is already available on http://metacpan.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its any consolation `Tie::CSV_File` seems to be [failing for everyone](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/T/Tie-CSV_File.html#Tie-CSV_File-0.21)! I will look around and try to provide some alternatives. <s>For now you might try installing a previous version which looks to be working better.</s> Never mind, it seems that the tests all fail for Perl versions > 5.8.

Update: I tried to patch the `Tie::CSV_File` to fix its flaws. I knocked a few problems off but couldn't fix it to my satisfaction. The closest other CPAN module is `Tie::Array::DBD`, although it claims to have very slow performance for CSV.

I have mocked up my own attempt to make a `tie`-able CSV Array, and have now released it to CPAN, entitled [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV), and available on [github](https://github.com/jberger/Tie-Array-CSV).

Comment: Thanks! I was beginning to think I was either missing something or crazy. It's good to know that it fails for everyone else, and not just for me.

Comment: I will take a look at your new module. But today being Friday, it might be a few days until I get back to it.

Comment: It will be there for you when you get to it, hopefully its helpful. Please let me know if you have any comments

Answer (score 0):

I work with a lot of csv file extracting information. An alternative to using Tie::CSV_FILE is just:

```
open my $file, '<', "filename.csv"; 

while(defined ( my $line = <$file> ) ){ 
  my @lineArray = split ',', $line; 
  my $firstValue  = $lineArray[0];
  my $secondValue = $lineArray[1]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this is an alternative, but not what I'm looking for. In the first place - if the CSV file has quoted strings, with embedded commas, then your split won't actually split the line correctly. In the second place - the Tie::CSV_File module is supposed to be able to let you access the ENTIRE CSV file as if it were a two dimensional array.